# update 9.0 on Mac not working - The proxy server is refusing connections

Tags: proxy

There used to be an option: Advanced > Network > Settings
that's gone, so can't even select No Proxy
Also, config:about network.proxy.socks_remote_dns : settings this to false doesn't work either

can we reinstall the good old version ?

Answer (score 0):

The option you speak of (Advanced > Network > Settings) has been moved. You can now find it by going to preferences > Tor. The Advanced proxy settings are found at the bottom of the page.

If removing the proxy doesn't fix the error, try one of this:

- Do you have an antivirus? It may be interfering with the Tor service.
  Try disabling the antivirus, if any.
- Did you by any chance move the Tor folder from its original location to a different location? If you did, revert this change.
- Check the port. Ideally, you should be on port 9050.
- Reinstall the program. But this time, make sure to install Tor Browser Bundle in a new directory, not over a previously installed bundle.

Comment: thank you, but how can I use the browser without the Tor network ? It used to be: config:about network.proxy.socks_remote_dns : false - but now this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @AndyM In addition to setting network.proxy.sock_remote_dns as false, have you tried setting extensions.torlauncher.start_tor to false and using no proxy?

Comment: yes, when I set network.proxy.sock_remote_dns and extensions.torlauncher.start_tor to false and settings no proxy, nothing happens. Then when I restart the browser, it's hosed again and says: The proxy server is refusing connections. The only way to recover from that is Settings - Help - Refresh Tor - Reconnect. So then I am connected to the Tor network again, but as mentioned I'd like to be able to use the browser without the Tor network